# Can you use Devise :timeoutable and :rememberable at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

And if so, how are they different that that is possible?

And if not, why do both exist? Why not have one without the other? If you don't have :timeoutable, then the session is automatically remembered. If you don't have :rememberable, then the session automatically times out.

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Timeoutable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Timeout:**

- *Session* based, `last_request_at` is saved in the session and checked very time before processing a request.
- There are a bunch of stuff done during the request to set `last_sign_in_at` in User model (which is used to set the `last_request_at` session variable). Please refer [trackable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb#L8) hook in devise, the flow is easy to track.

**Remember Me:**

- *Cookie* based, `remember_user_token` is stored as a cookie in the browser along with `remember_me_created_at` attribute in the devise model (User) in your database. [remember_me?](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb#L103) is called before each action to determine whether to continue without signing in.

***Both in place:***

If both timeout and rememberable is enabled in your application then rememberable overwrites the timeout flow.

[Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb#L26), you can see that `sign_out` happens after `timeout` only when `proxy.remember_me_is_active?(record)` is not true.

Comment: What do you mean by 'session'? Rails by default doesn't have sessions (like Java Servlets). The state of the user 'session' is stored in a signed, encrypted cookie. I assume your answer is "no they cannot be used together", because if the 'session' times out, then it will redirect to the login page even if they have a `remember_user_token` attribute in their cookie.

Comment: @Chloe - Sorry that I missed to mention the details in original answer, have updated now. Hope you can get your question clarified with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding/experience, which is not much, I see that:

Timeout functionality is intended for users with the browser open that might be away from keyboard and you want the session to expire for security reasons in a matter of minutes.

Remember Me functionality is intended for users that return daily or weekly and you do not want them to walk them through the login process each time. So you can remember them (for something around weeks or months usually). Which doesn't seem to work as expected is that remember me only works as expected when completely closing the browser app (tested in Firefox), if the user only closes the tab and opens a new tab they do not need to log in again, even if they asked not to be remembered.

As a final thought, I understand that when using timeout, remembering has no use.